# Is there a better way to write a changing image function?

Tags: javascript

I wrote a function that changes an image every 3 seconds. My question is, is this an acceptable way of accomplishing this or is there a better way? The reason I'm asking this is because some of the examples on here, that do this seem a bit overly complex. That makes me question if the complexity in those examples exists for a reason and if I'm missing something. thanks

```
            let timeout= function(){   
               //encapsulates data
                let index=0;
                let images=["https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRchcI27Cam2YzkA2vKlTimh6nvER7utm_HyjPu7gjlsljInp9L","https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRchcI27Cam2YzkA2vKlTimh6nvER7utm_HyjPu7gjlsljInp9L","https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS10D58-5V5cDC8V3vcHC4xKTFqGsnGg4ONyW6Khy-8iWJ9Xzy5xQ"];

                $(".gallery").attr("src",images[index]);//sets starting image

                return{
                    run: function(){
                        !function timeout(){
                            function changeImg(){
                                if(index===images.length-1){//resets cycle if needed
                                    index=0;
                                }
                                else{
                                    index++
                                }
                                $(".gallery").attr("src",images[index]);//changes image
                                timeout();//repeats
                            }
                            setTimeout(changeImg,3000);

                        }();

                    }
                }
            }();
            timeout=timeout.run;//redefines timeout as its returned object function  run
            timeout();//calls timeout
```

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's always a better way to write everything. :)

Here's my try:

https://jsfiddle.net/f1cgohh3/4/

```
let slide = document.getElementById('slide');
let slideIdx = 0;

let slides = [
  'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150/ff0000',
  'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150/00ff00',
  'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150/0000FF'
];

let slideShow = () => {
  slideIdx = slideIdx < slides.length - 1 ? slideIdx + 1 : 0;
  slide.src = slides[slideIdx];
};

slideShow();

setInterval(slideShow, 1000);
```

Comment: That's why this question is off topic and should be in code review. It will eventually be closed. Do not answer off topic questions but vote to close them instead. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer